# Django allauth login with google account

Tags: api, django-allauth

I  am using django-allauth and am trying to login to my website through gmail account. I have set up the api

Google API

```
Redirect URIs:  https://tutor.herokuapp.com/accounts/google/login/callback
JavaScript origins: https://tutor.herokuapp.com
```

But when I click on the Google link to sign in I get the error

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://tutor.herokuapp.com/accounts/google/login/callback/ did not match a registered redirect URI
```

I dont get exactly where I have gone wrong because Twitter and Facebook logins were successful. help pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have configured a HTTPS redirect URI, whereas your Django app is using HTTP URIs.
Either add `http://tutor.herokuapp.com/accounts/google/login/callback` over at the Google API console, or use HTTPS for your Django project.

Comment: Silly me, missed that. Can you also guide me on how to get yahoo login working too. Would be much helpful I already have the api created..Should I use the Openid or is there an explicit yahoo configuration

Comment: For now Yahoo's OAuth1 is not supported yet, Yahoo does offer OpenID  which is supported.